# A Specialized Guide for Deflating Variables: does it exist?

Tags: econometrics, statistics

I have done this very frequently in this year, deflating variables, specially for the purpose of demand estimation. I also asked a relevant question on the subject previously (here: [Heuristics with time series measured in dollars](https://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/8360/heuristics-with-time-series-measured-in-dollars)).

Since by my experience results can often change, depending on the index used, and you might have indexes that invalidate IV estimations (e.g. when in demand estimation one uses a instrument, a sectoral cost index, which might be related to the variable used for deflating the observations [by the way, here it is another question related to this particular subject that I've asked: [Does it make sense to 'deflate' a sectoral price index in a regression analysis?](https://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/5619/does-it-make-sense-to-deflate-a-sectoral-price-index-in-a-regression-analysis) ]), I was wondering if there is specialized guide to detail the various tips and/or problems you might run into when deflating variables. Does it exist?